# Now I am Getting Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object on my php form

Tags: php

Been fighting this code all day got most of the bugs hammered out but now im getting this error message

> Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object in /home/jsnow/public_html/registration.php on line 26

Here is my code:

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password']))
{
$db =connect('********','*********');
if($db!=false)
{
   register($db);
   echo "User registered";
}

}

function connect($dbuser,$dbpassword)
{
    try{
        $db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=jsnow_login', '*******' , '*********');
        return $db;
    }catch(PDOException $e){
        echo $e;
        return false;}
}

function register($db)
{
    $result_set = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO `users` (`username`, `password`) 
                            VALUES (:username, :password)");
 $result_set->execute(array(
':username' => $username, ':password' => $password
));

}




?>


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<form action="http://vps8383.***********.com/~jsnow/registration.php" method="post">
username:<input type="text" name="username"/>
password:<input type="password" name="password"/>
email<input type="text" name="e_mail"/>
<input type="submit"/>

</form>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Where are `$username` and `$password` passed to the register() function? And what `$pdo` in that function should be `$db`

Comment: Shouldn't that be something to the affect of `$result_set = $db->prepare` ?

Comment: Comments are just as good as answers ;-) you really need to pay attention to these, they're "priceless"

Comment: thanks for the comments guys I checked back and I saw there was an answer posted, I actually jumped the gun a little saying it works perfectly because even though the errors are gone information is not posting to the database from the form now.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Not exactly. There's a difference.

Comment: @JohnSnow: Mark Baker's comment is related to your new issue.

Comment: well any insight would be helpfull this was pretty much tutorial code pieced together because it was based on somebody using a mock server located on their computer and im using a testing server, So all in all when it comes to php and msqli im a compleet noob.

Comment: @JohnSnow I think it may be because of the first lines being **outside** your function starting with `if(isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password']))` down to the closing brace.

Comment: @JohnSnow Plus you need to define your variables like this `$username=$_POST['username'];` and `$password=$_POST['password'];` which have not been defined. You only checked if they were **set**

Comment: @Fred-ii- thanks for your help could you please give me an example on how i would go about doing that.... like i said earlier im a complete rookie Ive done simple mysql databases before but ive been told they were unsecure so thats why i went this route and now im just lost...

Comment: @JohnSnow You've actually gone further than I have in PDO, I'm still doing `MySQLi_` -- I'd like to give you an actual answer, but I can't... just not right now, but that's the gist of it. I'll see if I can get something working for you, but can't promise you anything, but I will try.

Comment: @JohnSnow I've got something working, however I couldn't figure out how to make it work with the functions you setup.

Comment: I think this has gone long enough. "Commentators" had their fair chance. @JohnSnow, please see my updated answer.

Comment: @geomagas Even though your effort could prove to be extremely helpful, there is one piece of code which won't work, due to its placement.

Comment: I answer _one_ question at a time. The latest was about two not initialized vars. When I see the next, I'll watch it being answered.

Comment: @JohnSnow I can show you what I came up with, if you're still interested John.

Answer (score 1):

Inside `register()`, `$pdo` is not defined. Use the following instead:

```
$result_set = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO `users` (`username`, `password`) 
                        VALUES (:username, :password)");
```

Concerning the `$sername` and `$password` variables not getting initialized in the function, change your function definition to:

```
function register($db,$username,$password)
```

and call it like this:

```
register($db,$_POST['username'],$_POST['password']);
```

Comment: @JohnSnow Hence [my original comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19413355/now-i-am-getting-fatal-error-call-to-a-member-function-prepare-on-a-non-objec#comment28778097_19413355) ;-)

Comment: Sorry @Fred -ii- im a noob and didnt catch your commment but I spoke too soon the code works and the errors are now gone but it is not updating my database now